# Python Read From File, Write in Reversed Order

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm doing an exercise from a book, and can't figure this out; this isn't homework, I'm trying to teach myself, and I have been trying anything that I can think of to make this work!

I need to read lines from a text file, and then write the lines into a new file, in reversed order.

My problem is, I can get it into reversed order (I'm assuming that it means last line of the 'r' file is printed first in the 'w' file), but it also prints the words reversed, making it unreadable.

Is there a way to possibly write the lines in reversed order, but the lines stay readable?

Here's what I have:

```
filetoread = 'yolo.txt'
file = open(filetoread, 'r')
words = file.read()
wrf = 'yip.txt'
wfile = open(wrf, 'w')


for lines in reversed(list(words)):
    print wfile.write(lines)
```

Comment: Simple: change `file.read()` to `file.readlines()`.

Comment: Thank you! I figured I was overlooking something simple

Comment: Also: Don't forget to close the files more [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Comment: @MarkRansom or dont put read or readlines ... since thats its iter behaviour anyway :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to note that it's usually easier and safer to use the `with` statement. That way you don't have to worry about opening a file and forgetting to close it. Plus, if an exception occurs inside the `with` block, the file is still closed automatically; you'd have to use a `try...finally` statement to do this without `with`.

Here's your example using `with`:

```
with open('yolo.txt', 'r') as readf, open('yip.txt', 'w') as writef:
    for line in reversed(readf.readlines()):
        writef.write(line)
```

Comment: Or push the work to the file objects themselves replacing the `for` loop with `writef.writelines(reversed(readf.readlines()))`

Comment: Good point. It's also worth noting that reading the entire file into memory with `readlines` probably isn't a good idea in general if you don't know how big the file is going to be.

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like

```
wfile.write("".join(reversed(list(open("some_file.txt")))))
```

Comment: Can't call `reversed` on a file iterator. If you could, you could save even more work with `wfile.writelines(reversed(open("some_file.txt")))`, but sadly, it's not legal.

Comment: meh i guess you could just wrap it in list (i edited it to do just this)